# Jenkins polling does not work after SVN update

Tags: svn, jenkins

Since our SVN server was updated (to 1.8), the polling within Jenkins does not work anymore, giving the stacktrace below.

I researched the problem and found similar errors related to Jenkins plugin, workspace version, repository version and SVN Kit implementation - but none could provide a solution for the problem. Has anyone experienced the same problem and was able to solve it?

```
Received SCM poll call on  for NGCS on Oct 21, 2013 11:26:09 AM
ERROR: Failed to check repository revision for [..]/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E210004: Number is larger than maximum
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:400)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:456)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:456)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:456)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:456)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readTuple(SVNReader.java:288)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.parse(SVNReader.java:241)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.read(SVNConnection.java:272)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.read(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1290)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.info(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1203)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:65)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:31)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2461)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.parseSvnInfo(SubversionSCM.java:1122)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:71)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:26)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SubversionSCM.java:1278)
    at hudson.scm.SCM._compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:356)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:373)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1567)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1490)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:439)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:468)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: svn: E210004: Number is larger than maximum
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNReader.readItem(SVNReader.java:399)
    ... 33 more
Done. Took 0.1 sec
No changes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like s snotty answer, but you could always try to rollback your SVN server to 1.7 or whatever you had before.

This is one of these unfortunate cases where the Jenkins server got forgotten when doing the SVN Server upgrade project.

Comment: Well, the SVN server is not in my hands, so I have to live with the version at hand. But I still not fully understand which part causes the problem. Is it the Jenkins SVN plugin or some other part? What I also don't understand is the fact, that the Jenkins job can checkout if started manually, but is not able to poll SVN correctly in order to start automatically after checkin.

Comment: Does the following link help you? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18844

Comment: I found the same link, but as you can see it's still unresolved, so what to do?

Comment: From last comment "The machine was rebooted and workspace deleted before test results. Implementing the 'svn upgrade' command with a Windows batch script in the job resolves the issue." - did you try this?

Comment: This comment indeed helped to solve the problem - I upgraded the svn client, upgraded the workspace and then upgraded the svn Jenkins plugin and now polling works again. Thank you for the hint!